# Unable to make the contentEditable dynamicallly for inline editing in angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i am a issue

below is my json data:

```
info = [{
    'id':1,'name': 'mr.x',
  },{
    'id':2,'name': 'mr.y',
  },{
    'id':3,'name': 'mr.z',
  },{
    'id':4,'name': 'mr.a',
  }]
```

i am displaying this in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let x of info;let i = index">
                            <div  id="{{x.id}}">


                            <div id="{{x.id}}">
                                        </div>
                                        <span [contentEditable]="content" id="{{x.id}}" > {{x.name}}</span>

                                         <button id="edit"  (click)="edit(x.id)">edit

                                         </button>
```

here what i am trying is for each span element the {{x.name}} is display i want to change that name and so what i did was

```
edit(id){

   this.content = true;

  }
```

it is not working  nothing editable

now my issues are **how can i make it editable based on click event and how can i get the value of the span and display the change as the change has to go to the server and display**

my stack link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdqxwx

Comment: if u can afford a new prop in your array it is simple n clean as it goes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihejkh

Comment: one small change how can i change the edit to save button  when i click the edit button and how can i get the values from renamed value and show after save

Comment: i cannot affor editaable prop  so thats the issue

Comment: you can switch back and forth edit/save try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xq2bpl

Comment: with out editable false cant we do that ?

Comment: ok i have to get the changed value thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick here is you need to create a dynamic property based on index i.e `PropertyName[i]`.

**Code:**

```
  hideElement = {}; // declare in .ts file
```

**Html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of info;let i = index">
 <div id="{{x.id}}">
    <div id="{{x.id}}">
  </div>
 <span [hidden]="!!hideElement[i]" id="{{x.id}}"> {{x.name}}</span>
 <input [(ngModel)]='x.name' type="text" [hidden]="!hideElement[i]" />
 <button id="edit" [hidden]='hideElement[i]' (click)="hideElement[i]=true">edit </button>
 <button id="save" [hidden]='!hideElement[i]' (click)="hideElement[i]=false">save </button>
</div>
```

working sample **[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmsyre)**

Comment: but how can i get the value from span after editing ?

Comment: simple u can try like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dsxtx . does it resolve your issue